# Ajax Dropdownlist using cascading dropdownlist in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, drop-down-menu, cascadingdropdown

I have data of quarters which are available in different area for different class of employee. So I want to populate area for 1st dropdownlist. On the basis of selection of area i want to populate second dropdownlist which will show the class of employee for whom quarters are available in that area.
Then I want to pass both these parameters to third dropdownlist which shows quarter names for that specific area and class of employee. The parameters for class dropdown is area which is of varchar parameter of area name and not a id of area? How  to implement this? Following is webmethod using in webservice

```
 [WebMethod]
    public CascadingDropDownNameValue[] GetClass(string knownCategoryValues)
    {
        string area = CascadingDropDown.ParseKnownCategoryValuesString(knownCategoryValues)["area"];
        string query = string.Format("SELECT build_id,build_pin FROM Building WHERE build_area = {0}",area);
        List<CascadingDropDownNameValue> states = GetData(query);
        return states.ToArray();
    }

private List<CascadingDropDownNameValue> GetData(string query)
    {
        string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Rent"].ConnectionString;
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);
        List<CascadingDropDownNameValue> values = new List<CascadingDropDownNameValue>();
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
        {
            con.Open();
            cmd.Connection = con;
            using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    values.Add(new CascadingDropDownNameValue
                    {
                        name = reader[0].ToString(),
                        value = reader[1].ToString()
                    });
                }
                reader.Close();
                con.Close();
                return values;
            }
        }
    }
```

Following is html code

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlClass" runat="server" Height="21px" Width="125px"></asp:DropDownList>
<asp:CascadingDropDown ID="cd_class" runat="server" TargetControlID="ddlClass" PromptText="Select Class" PromptValue="" ServicePath="~/ServiceCS.asmx" ServiceMethod="GetClass" Category="build_class" LoadingText="Loading..." ParentControlID="ddlarea"></asp:CascadingDropDown>
```

I am getting this error
**Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Fort' to data type int.**

though I select different area it takes the first value form table i.e. fort

Comment: Where's the code you are working on for this?

Comment: i want to populate 3rd dropdownlist also by passing area text and class text